# Changing index of summation index in Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Here is the question for context:

The number of claims occurring in a period has a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$. the insurer determines the conditional expectation of the number of claims in the period given that at least one claim has occurred, say $e(\lambda)$. Find $\lim_{\lambda\to 0} e(\lambda)$.

So the solution is provided, I'll point out the part I don't understand with an under-brace and question mark with my specific questions below:

Solution: $E[N|N\geq 1]=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty }n\cdot f(n|N\geq 1)=\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty }n\cdot \frac{f(n)}{1-f(0)}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty }n\cdot \frac{f(n)}{1-f(0)}}_{???}$

My specific question is: Why is it ok to change the summation index from 1 to 0 without changing anything else about the expression?

Comment: Because the term corresponding to $n=0$ on RHS vanishes.

Comment: but the index in the summation must be $n$ and not $i$

Comment: Thank you! When you say the term vanishes, what do you mean? Is this because it is being subtracted in the denominator?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
E[N|N\geq 1]&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }n\cdot f(n|N\geq 1)= \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n\cdot f(n|N\geq 1)= \\
&={\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n\cdot \frac{f(n)}{1-f(0)}=0 \frac{f(0)}{1-f(0)} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n\cdot \frac{f(n)}{1-f(0)}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }n\cdot \frac{f(n)}{1-f(0)}} \\
&= \frac{E[N]}{1-P(N=0)}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you all! One quick follow up semi-related question, the solution seems to imply that it was a necessary step to set the index =0 for $\sum^\infty n\cdot f(n)$ to be = to  the definition of $E[N]$. Is that necessarily the case? My textbook and many online sources seem to say that a definition of expectation can have an index starting at 1. Is anyone able to clarify this?

Comment: fixed index from i to n